# How can I resolve a fatal SQL statement error?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, syntax

I was having problems updating information in my SQL database using my vb.net application, but recently [I found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215825/problem-updating-mysql-database-help/7215865#7215865). However now I have run into another problem which is shown in the code below:

```
 Private Sub cmdupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdupdate.Click
   Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand

    '#######
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=" & frmLogin.txtserver.Text & ";" _
& "user id=" & frmLogin.txtusername.Text & ";" _
& "password=" & frmLogin.txtpassword.Text & ";" _
& "database=in_out"
    '#######

    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE event SET" _
        & "status = ?Status " _
        & "WHERE user_id = ?UserID AND message_id = ?MessageID AND creator = ?Creator"

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?UserID", myUserID)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?MessageID", cbomessage.SelectedValue)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Status", cbostatus.SelectedItem)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Creator", myUserID)
    myCommand.Connection = conn
    Try
        myCommand.Connection.Open()
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myCommand.Connection.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox("There was an error updating the database: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The exception message is:

> > Fatal error encountered during command execution.

I don't know if this is simply a syntax error that can be fixed easily, or something to do with my database configuration.

Comment: ok marc_s's solution below got rid of the error, and its updating the database now, but the vb.net application isn't displaying gthe changes in the data grid view control, it just keeps displaying the original information...

Comment: no, however i have a separate button control that, when clicked, retrieves the information from the database again (aka a refresh button)... idk if thats the problem or not but if it is id like an alternative

Comment: when i look at the information on my database from themysql control panel (not the vb.net program) its changed (with the information from the vb.net program) .... but when i look at the information that the vb.net program loads off the database, its still the old information (unchanged)

Comment: My guess is that your application reads from one place and saves into another one - different server or database or table? Move the code that builds the connection string into a separate method and use it in the `Update` and `Refresh` methods.

Comment: there is no code that builds the connection string, i just defined one based on the strings entered by the user in the login form's text boxes... but i think you may be right in saying that theres two places  that the information is being sent and recieved. i have a table called "events" which is where the information is being updated, and other tables called "user" and "status" which hold the information that the vb.net program recieves, but im not sure how to fix this. i think ill start a different question for this as this is getting off topic, but thanks!

Comment: The place where you *define the connection string based on the strings entered by the user in the login form's text boxes* is the **code that builds the connection string** and it should be extracted into a method that is called every time you need a connection string.

Comment: oh i see, and how does that fix any of my problems related to updating my database?

Comment: It probably won't fix this particular problem, but it will help you to become a better developer - it is one of many good practices that we all need to learn and use.

Comment: oh, alright well thanks! ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I decipher your screen shot correctly, then your UPDATE statement is being put together:

```
"UPDATE event SET" &
"status = ?Status" &
"WHERE user_id = ....... "
```

This results in:

```
UPDATE event SETstatus = ?StatusWHERE user_id = .......
```

so you're really only missing **some spaces**!

```
"UPDATE event SET " &    -- observe the SPACE after the SET !
"status = ?Status " &    -- observe the SPACE after the ?Status
"WHERE user_id = ....... "
```

Comment: ok i tried what you said and added the spaces, and the error isn't coming up anymore, however its still not updating the database with my changes... any thoughts?

Comment: @daniel11: if you run the query separately, in a SQL management tool - does it work there?? If not - check if all your conditions are met - with all your WHERE clauses - do you even get any rows at all (that meet those WHERE conditions?)

Comment: ok i checked the events log on my database and it turns out it did update the database but its not displaying the new information in my vb.net program... it seems to only display the original information

Answer (score 0):

Add space before  ;  on below

conn.ConnectionString = "server=" & frmLogin.txtserver.Text & ";" _

Thanks